# UTC to datetime conversion

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, utc

I have the following date time *string*:

> 2013-08-16T09:21:05-04:00

How can I get that into a local datetime format in VB.NET?

**UPDATE**

Just realised the string had some extra quotes on each side that hadn't been sanitized properly #blush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the DateTime.ParseExact() and DateTime.TryParse() methods.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime_methods.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this

```
    Dim s As String = "2013-08-16T09:21:05-04:00"
    Dim d As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dateValue As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2013-08-16T09:21:05-04:00")
Debug.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString)
```

Output on my machine (British English, GMT+1):

```
16/08/2013 14:21:05
```